# PHP bcmul() not using correct precision

Tags: php, bcmath

I'm trying to use the PHP bcmath library to handle the problem of rounding errors in PHP.

My code:

```
$usdPerCoin = 2755905;
$amountToConvert = 1000;

function toFixed(string $number, int $precision = 8): string
{
    $number = bcmul($number, (string) pow(10, $precision));
    return bcdiv($number, (string) pow(10, $precision), $precision);
}

die(var_dump(bcmul(toFixed($amountToConvert / $usdPerCoin, 8), (string) 1e8)));
```

Using this code with the following values produces different output I cannot comprehend.

```
$anountToConvert = 1000; // produces string(5) "36285"
$anountToConvert = 2000; // produces string(5) "72571"
```

When using `2000` as value for `$amountToConvert`, the amount of the previous conversion should be doubled, but as you can see it's not doubled.

I expect the values to be:

```
$anountToConvert = 1000; // produces string(5) "36285"
$anountToConvert = 2000; // produces string(5) "72570"
```

I think it's caused because it's using internal not only a precision of 8. Any ideas how to prevent this?

Comment: May or may not be a factor here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision

Comment: Well, `1e8 * 1000 / 2755905 = 36285.721024491`, and, `1e8 * 2000 / 2755905 = 72571.442048982`. That should explain everything. Your expectation is off.

Comment: You're concatenating a series of operations and just checking the final result. You may get some insight if you inspect individual operations one by one.

Also, beware that you're using an arbitrary precision library but you're casting numbers to string outside the library. It'll work mostly fine with small integers but you can eventually find issues if you ever pass floats or large numbers.